Maps Javascript API - InvalidValueError on refresh
On wordpress with Sage 9 theme, enqueueing the script as follows
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . $_ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API'] . '&loading=async&callback=initMap&libraries=marker,places&v=beta', [], null, true);


and creating a map like this
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 34, lng: 150 },
        zoom: 8,
    });
}

On refreshing the page I get this error in console
Uncaught (in promise) InvalidValueError

without any additional hint.
Landing on the page I can load the map.
I cannot trace back to the problem.
How can I debug this?

Could you please try to debug this with the help of console.log in your code. Here is the code for your reference.
function initMap() {     console.log('initMap function has been called.');     const mapElement = document.getElementById("map");     if (!mapElement) {         console.error('Map element not found.');         return;     }     map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {         center: { lat: 34, lng: 150 },         zoom: 8,     });     console.log('Map has been initialized.'); }
